# require JUST ActiveModel::Validations in an rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, activemodel

I have a class that I'm trying to test that includes `ActiveModel::Validations`

```
module SomeModule
  class SomeClass
    include ActiveModel::Validations
  end
end
```

I'm trying to test it without `spec_helper` to keep it fast, but a simple `require 'activemodel'` at the top of the spec doesn't work.  I keep getting an `uninitialized constant SomeModule::SomeClass::ActiveModel(NameError)`.  for the spec file:

```
require 'activemodel'

describe SomeModule::SomeClass do

end
```

Any tips on solving this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to include `active_model` in your module/class file.

```
# /some_class.rb

require 'active_model'

module SomeModule
  class SomeClass
    include ActiveModel::Validations
  end
end
```

Spec,

```
# /some_class_spec.rb

require './some_class'

describe SomeModule::SomeClass do

end
```

You'll want to change the paths to match your files. I doubt this will speed up your specs when run with other specs that include the whole Rails stack, but when run by itself this will be a little faster.